# Looking for similar projects: Iphone/Android + Google Maps + "external" database = sightseeing map

Tags: iphone, android, google-maps

sorry, it's not exactly a programming question, but I am currently in a research state and looking for similar projects, so I could analyze them:

It should be application to iPhone or Android or other mobile platform, where, basically, user can access map with "places of interest" and add it's own "place of interest" (with photo and description). Kind of, community generated sightseeing map.

I know it is quite simple and not a groundbreaking idea, but my google-fu is quite weak and I can't find anything like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

some links

http://appshopper.com/lifestyle/gastro-find

http://appshopper.com/navigation/where-to-eat-find-restaurants-using-gps

http://appshopper.com/travel/near-me-bc